# Team management website and mobile application

Tags: web-services, mobile, web

I'm looking to build a mobile/web based team management system, it will be around web development, database , services and mobile development.
The website should be very simple, and the web service should be efficient (as lest bandwidth as possible between the mobile application and it).
the site should be easily add and remove users and users will be with different accounts and different rules.
So as developer what web programming language do you suggest and what type of web service shall be built.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The language behind the scenes has little to do with how the website looks, works, and how much bandwidth it uses. Use a language you or your team are familiar with.

Comment: thanks for your reply , but what about the web service type ?

Comment: Virtually everyone these days seems to use REST or REST-like APIs. Which one to use is entirely up to you, based on your app.